# Resources to learn qt-dbus

Tags: qt, dbus

Please, could you provide me some resources (web-links) to learn qt-dbus?

I already have a process which provides `QtDBus` interface, I want to learn it so that I can communicate with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First hits from a Google search for `qt-dbus` and `qt-dbus tutorial`:

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/intro-to-dbus.html

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/QtDbus_quick_tutorial

http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials#D-Bus

There were many more interesting hits to list here. Their usefuleness to you depends on what you want to do, of course.

Answer (score 2):

**There are some more useful links since Dec '10:**

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtdbus.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-dbus.html

*In my opinion, this is the best tutorial to start:* http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials#D-Bus

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/QtDbus_quick_tutorial

http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/D-Bus/CustomTypes

**If you want to introspect D-Bus objects and messages you can use following tools:**

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qdbusviewer.html

https://wiki.gnome.org/DFeet

Answer (score 2):

Nokia has some great Maemo code that you can look off of. I found it's well documented and useful.

http://wiki.maemo.org/Documentation/Maemo_5_Developer_Guide/DBus/DBus_Basics

Comment: But maemo uses the low-level c API directly instead of qt-dbus.

Comment: True, but I've found Maemo to have some of the best explanations on what Dbus is and how it's used. The asker said "I want to learn it so that I can communicate with it." (referring to qt-dbus) and part of learning it is not just specific code, but theoretical. As with a meritocracy, the best answers get upvoted. This isn't the best answer, no. But I feel it still has merit.